# Highlighting a certain section of a plot

Tags: plotting

I assumed that the following plot for `Sin` would be red between `.5` and `.7`, but it's all blue. Am I misunderstanding what `Exclusions` do? The Help is rather uninformative.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, ExclusionsStyle -> Red, 
 Exclusions -> {.5 < Sin[x] < .7}]
```

Comment: 1. Did you only read the description at the beginning of document of `Exclusions`, etc. or even only check `?Exclusions`? It's important to read the examples in the document by pressing **F1** when using _Mathematica_. If you check them, you'll probably notice that, what you need is `ColorFunction`. (A strongly related example can be found in **Options** section of `Plot` document. ) 2. Why do you mention python's `eval` in the title? Is it another question?

Comment: `Exclusions` is to exclude singularities and documentation shows only equations, not inequalities, and some strings like `"Discontinuities"`.  To exclude part of a graph, you can use the option `RegionFunction` or `ConditionalExpression[Sin[x], Not[.5 < Sin[x] < .7]]`, but the excluded domain won't be colored. To color part of a graph, you can use `MeshFunctions` and `MeshShading`. Can you indicate what you want?

Comment: @MichaelE2 `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, If[.5 < y < .7, Red, Automatic]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False]`, I guess.

Comment: BTW, python's `eval` is amount to `ToExpression` of _Mathematica_, if I understand the document of `eval` correctly.

Answer (score 10):

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, Mesh -> {{.5, .7}}, 
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y}, y], 
 MeshShading -> {Automatic, Red, Automatic}, MeshStyle -> Green]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

[`Exclusions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exclusions.html) can be defined by equations but not by inequalities

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π},
 Exclusions -> {Sin[x] == 0.5, Sin[x] == 0.7},
 ExclusionsStyle -> {AbsolutePointSize[6], Red}]
```

[image]

Use [`ColorFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html) and [`ColorFunctionScaling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunctionScaling.html)

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π},
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y},
   Piecewise[{{Red, 0.5 < y < 0.7}}, Blue]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Another variation could be to plot a regular curve `p1` and superimpose the same curve on top of it constrained with a `RegionFunction` such as `p2` as follows.

```
p1 = Plot[Sin[x]
  , {x, 0, 2 π}
  , PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}
  ];

p2 = Plot[Sin[x]
  , {x, 0, 2 π}
  , PlotRange -> All
  , RegionFunction -> Function[{x}, 0.5 < Sin[x] < 0.7]
  , PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}
  ];

Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]